# How to set initial state empty when try to navigation to other page react native

Tags: react-native

I have a problem when i try to navigation.navigate called RegisterPage but before that i try to typing anycharacter in field email and after that i click register button and back again, but the field is not empty

LoginContainer.js

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import LoginComponent from '../../modules/LoginComponent/component/LoginComponent';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Toast } from '@ant-design/react-native';


class LoginContainer extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null,
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            post : [],
            email : '',
            password : '' ,
            showPassword: true,
        }

    }

    onValueChange = (text, name) => {
        this.setState({ 
            [name] : text 
        });
    }

    getPostAPI = () => {
        axios.get('http://10.2.62.212:3000/dataadmin')
        .then((res) => {
            this.setState ({
                post : res.data,
            })

        })
        .catch((err) => {

        })    
    }

    showPassword = () => {
        const showPassword = !this.state.showPassword
        this.setState({ showPassword });
    }

    onLoginPress = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const { post } = this.state;
        if(!this.state.email.trim()) {
            Toast.fail('Invalid Email', 1, undefined, false)   
        } else
        if(!this.state.password.trim()) {
            Toast.fail('Invalid Password', 1, undefined, false)
        } else
        if (post.find(e =>  `${e.email}${e.password}` === `${this.state.email}${this.state.password}` )) {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard');     
        } else
        if (post.find(e =>  `${e.email}${e.password}` !== `${this.state.email}${this.state.password}` )) {
            Toast.fail('Invalid Email or Password', 1, undefined, false)
        }
    }

    onRegistPress = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Register')                
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getPostAPI();    
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
            <LoginComponent
                navigation = {this.props.navigation}
                change = {this.props.change}
                onValueChange={this.onValueChange}
                showPassword={this.showPassword}
                onLoginPress={this.onLoginPress}
                showPassword={this.state.showPassword}
                onRegistPress = {this.onRegistPress}
            />
            </Fragment>
        );
    }

}



export default LoginContainer;
```

LoginComponent.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Button, Icon, Provider  } from '@ant-design/react-native';
import styles from '../../../../assets/styles/default.style'

class LoginComponent extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null,
    }

     render() { 

         return (
                <Provider >
                <View style={styles.containerLogin}>
                    <View style={styles.parentViewStyleLogin}>
                        <Text style={styles.textHeaderStyle}> Merchant APP </Text>

                        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Email</Text>
                        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                        <Icon style = {styles.styleIcon} name={"user"} color='black'/>       
                            <TextInput  
                                style={styles.textboxfield}
                                underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                                onChangeText={(text) => this.props.onValueChange(text, 'email')}         
                                placeholder = {'Input your email here'}
                                placeholderTextColor={'rgba(221,221,221,1)'}
                            />
                        </View>
                        <Text style={[styles.textStyle, {marginTop: 20}] }> Password </Text>
                        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                            <Icon style = {styles.styleIcon} name={"key"} color='black'/>
                            <TextInput
                                style={styles.textboxfield}
                                secureTextEntry={this.props.showPassword}
                                underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                                onChangeText={(text) => this.props.onValueChange(text, 'password')}
                                returnKeyType={'done'}
                                placeholder = {'Input your password here'}
                                placeholderTextColor={'rgba(221,221,221,1)'}
                            />
                        </View>
                        <TouchableOpacity  > 
                            <Button style={[styles.buttonTextStyle, { borderRadius : 30 }]}  onPress = {this.props.onLoginPress} >Login</Button>                           
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => this.props.onRegistPress()} > 
                            <Text style={styles.textDefault} >Dont have account ? Register</Text>                          
                        </TouchableOpacity>


                    </View>
                </View>
                </Provider>
            );
        }
    }




export default LoginComponent
```

navigation

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import LoginContainer from '../../app/LoginContainer/LoginContainer';
import DashboardContainer from '../../app/DashboardContainer/DashboardContainer';
import NotificationContainer from  '../../app/NotificationContainer/NotificationContainer';
import TransactionContainer from '../../app/TransactionContainer/TransactionContainer'
import RegisterContainer from '../../app/RegisterContainer/RegisterContainer'
import DetailContainer from '../../app/DetailContainer/DetailContainer';

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Login: { screen: LoginContainer },
        Dashboard: { screen: DashboardContainer },
        Notification: { screen: NotificationContainer },
        Transaction : { screen: TransactionContainer },
        Register : { screen : RegisterContainer },
        Detail : { screen : DetailContainer }

    },
);


export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

this my ui
[image]
[image]

look after i try to type anycharacter and then directly click signup , and then click sigin again , and the field is not empty. i dont know how to fix it

Comment: before going to other page clear fields like this. :
`onRegistPress = () => {
this.state.email = ""
this.state.password = ""
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Register')                
    }
`

Comment: still same , the emty still not empty

Comment: It looks like you even though your textfield change some values (`onChangeText={(text) => this.props.onValueChange(text, 'password')}`), it doesn't seem that they are using those values to display text (there is no `value` prop on your textfields).

You could take those values and pass them to your textfields. This would make them 'controlled' inputs, and when you clear them in the LoginContainer it would be reflected in the login component. This would mean you don't need to do `navigation.push` (which is not ideal as it can result in a lot of screens being pushed on the stack).

Comment: yeahh i understand now , before im suing react js to create my project but now im using react native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are 2 ways you can achieve this :

1. While you click on register in the DOnt have account text , then before navigation.navigate you can set the state of email to '' , like

   `onRegisterClick = () =>{
   this.setSTate({email:''});//first this
   this.props.navigation.navigate('Register');//then this
   }`
2. You can go back to the login page again by `this.props.navigation.push('Login')` rahther than navigation.navigate coz what navigate does is it calls the page from existing stack ,and push creates a new stack so values will be reset  , so email will be null

Comment: thankyou, solvedd.. but i have a question . so push to make value null and navigate to create existing page. but this is how im confused. which condition i should use navigate and push . liek to dashboard, or something

Comment: see , when you are returning back from signup page to login, then use push so that email id field gets cleared

Comment: broo i changed the form into redux form, i already use push but still not empty.

Comment: if its redux then you have to use my first method and call that action to set email field to ' '

Comment: redux-form broo.